# Defauly Bit rate while record audio by Android phone

Tags: android

I am working on one Android Application, In this app I like to record audio. 
And for Information I used  these parameter :-

```
 recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);  
 recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

But now I like to know what is the default bit rate to record an audio in android . Can anybody help me?

Thanks In Advance
Vaibhav Singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just look at the fist byte data

04 means 4.75
0c means 5.15 
.... etc. if u are using 2.3.13, default bit rate should be 4.75kbit/s